# How to handle form data in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i have a form for adding people object ,i want to add as many people without saving people in database,after clicking add people form submit button,the same form should appear without saving the form data to database,instead it should save to the session.please explain in detail if possible with the help of a example to do this, i have not found any tutorial which explains cakephp session in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are simple. You include the component, write something to the session and read it from the session later. That's it. You can store in it almost anything you want, including arrays.

```
class FooController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Session');

    public function foo() {
        $this->Session->write('some.key', 'some value');
    }

    public function bar() {
        $baz = $this->Session->read('some.key');
    }

}
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/view/1311/Methods

Comment: i want to know how to store form data in session variables ,the answer what you replied is not related to the question i asked

Comment: @Vinay With all due respect, please try to *understand* my answer first. Form data is available in `$this->data`. You can store it in the session simply by writing it to the session: `$this->Session->write('formdata', $this->data);`

Comment: i am very new to cakephp and i dont about session handling also,thats why i commented like that,please you need to help me and i apologize for that comment.

Comment: i have two models person and delegate and the relation between them is Person hasOne delegate and delegate belongsTo person,now i have written a form to add delegate when add delegate button is clicked the same form should display but the data should be saved in session ,when next button is clicked it should go to another page where another form will display and after that data in the session should be saved to database tables,i have created only the page where it has one form to capture delegate details ,please explain me what to do next

Answer (score 3):

Vinay,

check out [the official examples.](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1465/Session#!/view/1310/Sessions)
But you should definitly start with the easy tutorials [here](http://book.cakephp.org//view/1528/Blog) and dissect these. You will learn form handling and later can put it together with the sessions.